# How checking eloquent relationship adds the hasOne model to the $user object?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I wanted to insert the store object in the `$user` object if the user has a store. So I tried this it added store as an `$user` object child and a seperate object too:

```
$user = Auth::User();

if($user->store != null){
    $store = $user->store();
}
else {
    $store = null;
}

return response()->json(compact('token', 'user','store'));
```

But even after this it works (It adds the store as a child of `$user` ):

```
$user = Auth::User();

if($user->store != null){
    //air
} else {
    store = null;
}

return response()->json(compact('token', 'user'));
```

I'm surprised how is that? This adds store as an attribute containing the respective store object and null if its not there. Can you explain how this works?

Answer (score 0):

The store is already on the user since you are accessing it. You should also examine that if else.

```
   if($user->store != null){
       $store = $user->store();
    }else { $store = null; }
```

is the same as just saying:

```
$store = $user->store();
```

Comment: Yeah but how is so? Without explicitly setting the object child how it's coming there?